# Can not run Angular APP through docker container

Tags: angular, docker

I am facing one issue. I have deployed my simple angular APP inside docker container and after successfully running when I am ruing the URL on browser its not working. I am giving the command below.

I run the docker using below command

```
-sudo docker run -d -it -p 90:90/tcp --name parent subhrajyoti/parent:latest
bcf00b41f1df8d1f9bf539613543d4a32e52cd01ffd1c2c7cf2d4070839b461e
```

After running successfully when I run the following command on browser

```
http://localhost:90/
```

The angular page is not coming its showing below error.

```
This site can’t be reachedThe web page at http://localhost:90/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
```

I need to resolve that issue and run my angular APP deployed on docker container.

Comment: can you paste the Dockerfile at least so we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: yes, please provide the docker file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that Angular runs on port 90 in docker because if you use Nginx it uses port 80 by default.
Would it work if you changed your docker command to the following?

```
-sudo docker run -d -it -p 90:80/tcp --name parent subhrajyoti/parent:latest
bcf00b41f1df8d1f9bf539613543d4a32e52cd01ffd1c2c7cf2d4070839b461e
```

Comment: Ok, let me to try this. Before one contaier is running in port 80 and that was like 80:80/tcp so I changed it to 90:90.

Comment: Yes, As per you I made the changes and now its working.